# Sniffing ldap credentials?

Tags: network, penetration-test, sniffing, ldap

I am going to performing an internal pentest. Is it possible to sniff active directory credentials using Wireshark or Ettercap when a user logs on and authenticates to using their domain credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided a server is involved in the authentication process, **yes**, it is possible to sniff the login credentials.

Comment: the server would be a windows domain controller does Microsoft encrypt the password before sending it to the domain controller

Comment: Yes, the password will be encrypted with AES-128 encryption.

Comment: thank you so much for your time in answering my question. Also would I be able to capture this password and maybe replay it like a pass the hash. It seams kind of pointless to encrypt the password if data can be sent in cypertext.

Comment: Yes, I believe it is possible for a pass the hash attack to be done in this way.